# Solving the transport equation with an initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have $$\begin{cases}
u_t + x^2 u_x = 0\\
u(x,0) = x
\end{cases}$$
I found that the general solution is $$u(x,t) = f\left(-\frac{1}{x} - t\right)$$
Applying the initial condition 
$$u(x,0) = f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) = x$$
Then I thought we would have $$u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{x} - t$$ which checks out but it does not satisfy the initial condition. So I am wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: Well, if $f\left(-\frac{1}{y}\right) = y,$ as you have shown, then $f\left(-\left(\frac{1}{x} + t\right)\right) = f\left(-\frac{(1+tx)}{x}\right) = \frac{x}{1 + tx}$. Essentially, $f$ acts on the entirety of its input, it doesn't magically know that some part comes from $x$ and behave differently on just that part.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Can you explain this further I still do not understand

Comment: $f$ is a function of a single variable. You want to determine $f(u),$ where $u = -(x^{-1} + t)$ is your canonical variable. You found that for any input, say $y$, $f(-1/y) = y$. Therefore, $f(u) = -1/u$. Now plug in the value of $u$ in terms of $x,t$. The idea is that $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It cannot sniff out that the argument given to it is composed of two different variables. Analogously, suppose $g(x) = x^2.$ What is $g(2x)$? $g(xy)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found that the general solution is $$u(x,t) = f\left(-\frac{1}{x} - t\right) \tag 1$$
Applying the initial condition 
$$u(x,0) = f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right) = x$$
The goal is to determine the function $f$.

Let $\quad X=-\frac{1}{x}\quad\to\quad x=-\frac{1}{X}\quad$ , thus :
$$f(X)=-\frac{1}{X}$$
Now the function $f$ is determined. We have to put it into equation (1) where the variable is $$\quad X=-\frac{1}{x} - t$$
This no longer $X=-\frac{1}{x}$ as above, since $t$ is no longer equal to $0$.
$$f\left(-\frac{1}{x}-t\right)= -\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{x} - t}$$

$$u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{x} - t} = \frac{x}{1+xt}$$